# Is there an alternative to Fragments to build reuseable components in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building an application using Android Studio for an android tablet.  I am fairly new, have never published an application.  I have several parts I use on more then one page so I implemented them as fragments.  On the page I am working on uses 4 fragments and when it renders, I get the message, Skipped 36 frames.  If I change the fragment body from the page xml file to a constraints layout the messages go away. I've cut each of the fragments down to bare bones to get then number of skipped frames down to 36.  If I put the components back in, the skipped frames go to 96.

Is there an alternative to fragments to share code within android?

I have run systrace for the loading of the page and the measure took 1441.6ms while the layout took 8.31ms.

There are other problems of course, but sorting out how to get this down to something reasonable would be good.

Also, Could this just be that the tablet is slow?  Is there a place to see benchmarks on specific devices?  Then I could maybe just use a different device.

**Edit**
If I flatten the xml, replace the fragment and put the xml for the fragment inline using a surrounding <ConstraintLayout it is slightly worse?

**Edit II**
I have worked on this issue all morning.  I went back to the fragment implementation, then I went through the process of removing some ConstraintLayout sections.  I used ConstraintLayout to delineate areas on the display.  So I figured I could increase performance if I could remove some of them.  Well, not so fast, sometimes when I removed the ConstraintLayout it actually made the application skip more frames.

Then I did an experiment on where I used margins and borders.  It turns out if you use margins on a ConstraintLayout is faster, depending on the content of the Constraintlayout, then adding padding to each of the elements.

Also, a bigger cost is asking the ConstraintLayout to fill all available space using height/width="0dp"  All of these attributes are part of the measure phase so they impact the frames skipped.

My consensus is that the tablet doesn't have enough power to write an application that makes any good use of the screen.  Think of the tablet as the screen real estate of 4 phones.  If the cpu is not way bigger it will not be able to manage that size of a display, unless all you want to do is draw images on it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your screen design? Fragments are often quite efficient, but it could be the XML design (nested LinearLayouts, etc) that cause the lag. It could also be placement of the fragment within the Activity. And normally ConstraintLayout performs a little better.

Comment: I have many nested ConstraintLayout, it is a 10" screen and I used fragments to form rows and columns.  I use horizontal_weight and vertical_weight to segment the space and this might also be a contributor.  I am going to go back the the fragments.  I have to leave now, I will post the main page xml that includes the fragments later tonight.

Comment: Ah, the purpose of ConstraintLayout is so that nothing has to be nested. Nested ViewGroups are very inefficient. It should be one Fragment visible on the screen at a time, or maybe two on a tablet (e.g. master-detail layout).

Comment: @Muz I have a 10" display that can show plenty of information, are you suggesting all of it be built with one or two ConstraintLayout instances?  One Fragment visible on the screen at one time means I can't have any because the Navigation technology makes each page a Fragment.

Comment: Maybe you could show a wireframe of your design so we could give a suggestion? It should be able to handle, say, the complexity of Stack Overflow on desktop just fine for most devices. Usually you only need one ConstraintLayout parent for the whole fragment. If you have things like lists, they can be optimized in RecyclerViews, though the items in the RecyclerViews themselves might be ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In July 2021 Google [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/jetpack-compose-announcement.html) [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), a "modern toolkit for building native UI" with a reactive programming model. It is Google's recommended approach of developing new Android apps but can also be integrated into existing apps that use Fragments or plain Android views.